# How can I control docker using python script

Tags: python, docker

Such as a python file
example.py:

```
import os

containerId = "XXX"
command = "docker exec -ti " + containerId + "sh"
os.system(command)
```

when I execute this file using "python example.py", I can enter a docker container, but I want to execute some other commands inside the docker.

I tried this:

```
import os

containerId = "XXX"
command = "docker exec -ti " + containerId + "sh"
os.system(command)
os.system("ps")
```

but `ps` is only executed outside docker after I exit the docker container,it can not be executed inside docker.

so my question is how can I execute commands inside a docker container using the python shell.

By the way, I am using python2.7. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you try this one? https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 1):

If the commands you would like to execute can be defined in advance easily, then you can attach them to a `docker run` command like this:

```
docker run --rm ubuntu:18.04 /bin/sh -c "ps"
```

Now if you already have a running container e.g.

```
docker run -it --rm ubuntu:18.04 /bin/bash
```

Then you can do the same thing with `docker exec`:

```
docker exec ${CONTAINER_ID} /bin/sh -c "ps"
```

Now, in `python` this would probably look something like this:

```
import os

containerId = "XXX"
in_docker_command = "ps"
command = 'docker exec ' + containerId + ' /bin/sh -c "' + in_docker_command  + '"'
os.system(command)
```

This solution is useful, if you do not want to install an external dependency such as [`docker-py`](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) as suggested by [@Szczad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1286750/szczad)